# How to get permissions from a user that has multiple roles in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-5.8

I'm building a new laravel application, where a user can have multiple roles and these roles have multiple rights **(permissions)**. Now i want to get all the permissions from a certain user.

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and Eloquent. I can get the roles from a user an permissions from a role, but not the permissions from a user.

```
 dd(Auth::user()->roles->rights);
```

Model user:

```php
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
```

Model role:

```php
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function rights()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Right::class);
    }
```

Model right

```php
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
```

I'm expect to get all permissions for one user past trough by the roles he has.

Comment: Try with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56631895/get-user-permissions-list/56631972#56631972

Comment: Now i'm using the load method and i get the rights if i dump them, but i can't access them.
dd(Auth::user()->load('roles.rights'));
https://imgur.com/cwK0bXP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since One User can have many roles and one role can have many rights,
you will need to loop through each roles

```
//Retrieving rights associated with the user
public function retrieveRightsAssociatedWithUser($user){
    $rightsAssociatedWithUser = [];
    foreach($user->roles as $role){
        $rightsAssociatedWithUser[] = $role->rights; 
    }
    return $rightsAssociatedWithUser;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a better solution? I don't like to do a foreach in a foreach even if you can cache the permissions. At the moment i am using        
 dd(Auth::user()->load('roles.rights'));
This is given me a collection of rights but i can access them

Comment: No. I am not aware of any other alternatives to retrieve the data right now. You can eagarload the permission and roles to make if faster.

Comment: You can remove one foreach and retrieve all the rights with one foreach. I have updated my answer. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can add to method rights() to User model:

```
public function rights()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Role::class, Right::class);
    }
```

and then use $user->rights();

---

Additional info:
Laravel has't Thought for manyToMany.

You can install pakage

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep
```

and use this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function rights()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Right::class, ['role_user', Role::class]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! If i do this i get this error.
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rights.user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `roles`.*, `rights`.`user_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `roles` inner join `rights` on `rights`.`id` = `roles`.`right_id` where `rights`.`user_id` = 200)

Comment: @Arne, Sorry I confused, please try return $this->hasManyThrough( Right::class, Role::class);

Comment: I noticed your small mistake, but it didn't solve my problem. I still get een SQLSTATE-error
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `rights`.*, `roles`.`user_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `rights` inner join `roles` on `roles`.`id` = `rights`.`role_id` where `roles`.`user_id` = 200)`

Comment: @Arne, Sorrym Laravel Has not thorough for many to many, you can install https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep and use 
class User extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function permissions() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Permission::class, ['role_user', Role::class]);
    }
}

Comment: Thanks, i will make use of it in the future, i now just write my own SQL-statement and that works. I will have a look at your solution.